# Unable to return Mono<Compliance>

Tags: java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to retrieve Mono from DB and then filter the Compliance List which is inside the PortCall object based on one condition and finally return a Compliance or Mono

Below is my Mongo DB query

```
@Query("{vesselCode : ?0, arrivalVoyageCode: ?1}")
Mono<PortCall> findDeadlineTimestamp(String vesselCode, String arrivalVoyageCode);
```

Below is the usage in ServiceImpl to retrieve Mono

```
Mono<Compliance> cmp = portCallRepository.findDeadlineTimestamp(arrivalVoyageCode, vesselCode)
            .doOnNext(p->p.getCompliance().stream()
            .filter(c->c.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(compId))).subscribe();
```

Comment: What's the error/problem? You say you're unable, then show us some code. Does the code work? Compile? If not, how?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Already code is there in the body of the question, aren't you able to see?

Comment: Yes, I can see your code. But I don't see what's wrong with it. What errors are you getting? You can't expect that everyone just compiles your code (especially if you only provide a tiny sliver of it). If you have an error, you should always explain 1. what you expect to happen, 2. what happens insteand and 3. give the exact error messages, if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Reactor's operators instead of Java 8 streams.

The expected way to do that is to actually use the [map](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) operator along with the [filter](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-):

```
Mono<Compliance> getCompliance() {
    return portCallRepository.findDeadlineTimestamp(arrivalVoyageCode, vesselCode)
            .map(e -> e.getCompliance())
            .filter(c -> c.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(compId));
}
```

Then, caller will subscribe:

```
getCompliance().subscribe()
```